# How to replace setTimeout in Angular

Tags: angular, settimeout

I wonder how can i replace setTimeout() in Angular.

I have got something like this

```
  public resetSelect: boolean = false;

  private clearSelection(): void {
    this.resetSelect = true;
    this.myForm.get('time').setValue(null);
    this.myForm.get('colors').setValue(null);
    this.myForm.removeControl('drinks');
    this.myForm.removeControl('food');

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.resetSelect = false;
    }, 200);
  }
```

resetSelect is set to true, to call a function by @Input() in other component.

Comment: Look at ngOnChanges hook.

Comment: @JSonChild Can you give some additional informations about what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rxjs timer operator

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs'

timer(200).subscribe(_=>{
  this.resetSelect = false;
})
```

But really I don't know what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to false when you are detecting input change in child component itself.